# E488: Trailing characters in keymapping

Tags: key-bindings

Here is my command:
`nnoremap <Leader>pwd :!pwd | tr -d '\n' | xclip<CR>`

And I get error like this how to fix it? I havent found something useful to my issue

```
Error detected while processing BufWritePost Autocommands for "/home/li                                                                          │
│zhe/.config/nvim/init.vim"..script /home/lizhe/.config/nvim/init.vim:                                                                            │
│line  422:                                                                                                                                       │
│E488: Trailing characters: -d '\n':  tr -d '\n'
```

I try to escape my command but not work either like:
`\-d \'\n\'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a keybinding, you have to replace the vertical bars with `<Bar>`.

```
nnoremap <Leader>pwd :!pwd<Bar>tr -d '\n'<Bar>xclip<CR>
```

For explanation, see `:h map-bar`:

```
Since the '|' character is used to separate a map command from the next
command, you will have to do something special to include  a '|' in {rhs}.
There are three methods:
   use       works when                    example      ~
   <Bar>     always                        :map _l :!ls <Bar> more^M
   \|        'b' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls \| more^M
   ^V|       always                        :map _l :!ls ^V| more^M

(here ^V stands for CTRL-V; to get one CTRL-V you have to type it twice; you
cannot use the <> notation "<C-V>" here).
```